# Error expected type with actual type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, compiler-errors, functional-programming

I declared these types in Haskell :

```
data Tree x = Node x (Tree x) (Tree x)
          |Leef
          deriving Show

data Color = R | N
    deriving (Show, Eq)

data TreeRN x = Tree (Color,x)
    deriving Show
```

and this function :

```
equilibre :: TreeRN a -> TreeRN a
equilibre (Node (N,z) (Node (R,y) (Node (R,x) a b) c) d) = (Node (R,y) (Node (N,x) a b) (Node (N,z) c d))
equilibre (Node (N,z) (Node (R,x) a (Node (R,y) b c)) d) = (Node (R,y) (Node (N,x) a b) (Node (N,z) c d))
equilibre (Node (N,x) a (Node (R,z) (Node (R,y) b c) d)) = (Node (R,y) (Node (N,x) a b) (Node (N,z) c d))
equilibre (Node (N,x) a (Node (R,y) b (Node (R,z) c d))) = (Node (R,y) (Node (N,x) a b) (Node (N,z) c d))
```

And here is my issue :

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘TreeRN a’
            with actual type ‘Tree (Color, t3)’
Relevant bindings include
  d :: Tree (Color, t3) (bound at test.hs:15:53)
  c :: Tree (Color, t3) (bound at test.hs:15:51)
  z :: t3 (bound at test.hs:15:48)
  b :: Tree (Color, t3) (bound at test.hs:15:37)
  y :: t3 (bound at test.hs:15:34)
  a :: Tree (Color, t3) (bound at test.hs:15:23)
  equilibre :: TreeRN a -> TreeRN a (bound at test.hs:12:1)
  (Some bindings suppressed; use -fmax-relevant-binds=N or -fno-max-relevant-binds)
In the expression:
  (Node (R, y) (Node (N, x) a b) (Node (N, z) c d))
In an equation for ‘equilibre’:
    equilibre (Node (N, x) a (Node (R, y) b (Node (R, z) c d)))
      = (Node (R, y) (Node (N, x) a b) (Node (N, z) c d))
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Usually when I get this kind of error I understand why and I can correct my function, but here I am disappoint by the

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘TreeRN a’
            with actual type ‘Tree (Color, t3)’
```

while my declared type TreeRN is the same (for me), so I need answer for why the compiler say 't3', what does it mean ? It is really different to Tree (Color,a) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are expecting `TreeRN x` to be a synonym for `Tree (Color, x)`.  I think you have just used the wrong keyword -- `data` defines a new algebraic data type. Try

```
type TreeRN x = Tree (Color, x)
```

You will also need to remove the `deriving` clause which is not valid for type synonyms.

Comment: Thanks to you, I understand now, I admit that I didn't know the difference between data and type. So I didn't think about it.